# What are symbols like >, < and = called in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write an error handler,

so something like this example:

```
time = int(input"Is the number greater (>), lesser (<) or equal (=)? "))

except ValueError
 print ("Incorrect Input!")
```

However, I want the user to input a symbol, does anyone know if there is anything I can use instead of int for this?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: A string? Some more information is needed. Regarding your question - these are called `Comparison Operators`.

Comment: I mean, instead of an integer, is there another input I can ask for, specifically asking for the symbols <,> or =?

Comment: The name of the constructs are comparison operators / assignment operator; these are part of the Python language grammar itself — https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an operator type in Python, so you would have to keep them as a string and then check if the input is one of those three, and then determine which one it is and respond accordingly.

```py
while True:
    op = input("Is the number greater (>), lesser (<) or equal (=)? ")
    if op == '>':
        # Operator is >
        break;
    elif op == '<':
        # Operator is <
        break;
    elif op == '=':
        # Operator is ==
        break;
    else:
        print("Invalid operator. Please try again. ")

# use operator
```